# How to have data consistent across the templates with Django?

Tags: django, templates

How can I have the same data (like users related stuff that goes into a menu) consistent all over the templates using a base template without having to provide that data from each and every view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide the same data to your template accross all views using [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext), and then use [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) to include the same formating for every pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can add variables to the `RequestContext` - [see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) - the variables added will then be avaliable in each view as long as you use `RequestContext`.